# Terraform with Azure - Resource actions symbols dont display correctly in the logs

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

When deploying a terraform task via Azure, the resulting logs dont display the resource symbols correctly.

```
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4807821Z An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4808173Z Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4808433Z   [32m+[0m create
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4808648Z   [33m~[0m update in-place
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4808823Z [0m
2020-03-16T22:19:21.4809040Z Terraform will perform the following actions:
```

Wondering if its possible to get the correct symbols instead of the 32m+, etc.

[image: Azure release logs]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix those weird characters just use the **-no-color** option on your plan and apply steps!

[image: Setting the -no-color option]

[image: And after it was fixed:]

And for reference those weird values represent colors of the terminal - see: https://github.com/shiena/ansicolor/blob/master/README.md

No-Color option: https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html#no-color

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing ANSI codes, setting your Git Bash terminal to support `xterm-256color` is one way to see these (usually invisible) codes.

Comment: this deployment is happening in the cloud via Azure Devops, so wondering what I should do there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Knowing what those codes were allowed me to quickly figure out the fix. Without that, I thought it was a missing font or something